# Ubuntu Open Stack

Tags: openstack

Please what's the usefulness of Ubuntu open stack.I have been seeing it every site i go to so i'm wondering how useful it can be. I'd appreciate answers. I am  a newbie here so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is the world’s most popular operating system for OpenStack.

Indeed it will be a long answer to state all properties but you have to read this http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/ubuntu-openstack if you are interested in.

In this link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack you can find how to install and manage.

Anyway, it's better to give a try so you can test it yourself